# Reading password input from console

Tags: php, security, console

I am writing an installation script in PHP, where the user has to enter the username and password of the root MySQL user.

Currently I use:

```
fgets(STDIN)
```

to read the username and password, but this is not secure because other people might glance and see the password typed.

Is there a way to input the password from the user, such that it will look like this: "******", similar to how it looks like in a webpage?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a one-size-fits-all solution, but look at the similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187736/command-line-password-prompt-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297850/is-it-really-not-possible-to-write-a-php-cli-password-prompt-that-hides-the-pass

Comment: As it is an installation script why not just warn the installer that this is the case. It is a one off event and hardly seems worth the effort.

Comment: Found your answer from other stackoverflow questions ..Hope that helps.(LInk provided below) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187736/command-line-password-prompt-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297850/is-it-really-not-possible-to-write-a-php-cli-password-prompt-that-hides-the-pass Hope this helps ..:)

Answer (score 1):

We can't store like `'*****'` literally. But you can make it hard to recover.

I put some hash in my web config, as an environment variable, say MYSQL_PASS_HASH

Then I do something like `md5(getenv('MYSQL_PASS_HASH').'gibberish$qwefsdf')` which is then the password.

Your password will not literally be stored somewhere, and it can be recovered only when someone has both you web config and your database include.